# Mozilla XUL > Add-ons-Manager layout / skin?

Tags: xul, xulrunner

I'm looking for a documentation about Mozilla's Add-ons-Manager layout or XUL-templates - does anybody know the name of this tabbed-layout on the left-row ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [`<richlistbox>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/richlistbox) element with custom styling. Element ID is `categories` and some styles from http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/themes/winstripe/mozapps/extensions/extensions.css apply to it - look at the styles specified below `/*** category selector ***/` comment. Note that I linked to the Windows theme, the styles are different on other platforms.

You can use [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) to look at the structure of that page yourself.